# Python tabulate: how to print specific cell content?

Tags: python, pandas, tabulate

I have this code:

```
from tabulate import tabulate                                                                                                                                           
import pandas                                                                                                                                                     

df = pandas.DataFrame({'Col2' : ['Hello', 'How' , 'Are', 'You'],                                                                                                            
                   'Col3' : ['Hi', 'I', 'am', 'fine']})                                                                                                                 
nice_table = tabulate(df, headers='keys', tablefmt='psql')                                                                                                              
print(nice_table)
```

It prints this:

```
+----+--------+--------+                                                                                                                                                
|    | Col2   | Col3   |                                                                                                                                                
|----+--------+--------|                                                                                                                                                
|  0 | Hello  | Hi     |                                                                                                                                                
|  1 | How    | I      |                                                                                                                                                
|  2 | Are    | am     |                                                                                                                                                
|  3 | You    | fine   |                                                                                                                                                
+----+--------+--------+
```

Is there a way to access and print the content of a given cell of **`nice_table`**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Keep in mind that `tabulate`'s sole purpose is as mentioned in the documentation is to:

> Pretty-print tabular data in Python

Moreover if you run `type(nice_table)` you'll see that `tabulate` returns a `string`. Therefore for any operations other than pretty printing the dataframe you will have to work with `df`.

Answer (score -1):

```
df.loc[[2, 'Col3']]
#am
df.loc[[0, 'Col2']]
#Hello
```

for more information:
[pandas.DataFrame.loc](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html)

Comment: I am getting: `KeyError: "None of [['2', 'Col3']] are in the [index]"                                                                                                                  
`

Comment: Apologies, I had thought you set the index to strings.  
I've editted the answer to reflect the correct one. `df.loc[[2, 'Col3']]` and `df.loc[[0, 'Col2']]`